# Changing properties of a view during drag

Tags: java, android

I have this code in the `ACTION_DOWN` of my `onTouch(View v)` method as follows...

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);     
    view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
    myOnClickListener.onClick(view);
    return true;
}
```

Now my view in this case is a ChessPiece. I have `chessPiece.setBackground(R.color.black)` and `chessPiece.setImageBitmap(pawnBitmap)`.

Currently when I drag the chess piece, it drags the background color with it, which I dont want. So is there anyway to remove the background of the view when it's dragging so that the `DragShadow` is just of the bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own dragshadow. This example helped me when I wanted to play with the dragshadow: http://lemonycode.blogspot.be/2012/11/using-custom-dragshadowbuidler-in.html

As you can see, there are two important methods:

```
public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point touchPoint)
```

and:

```
public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas)
```

The first method is used to size the dragshadow and the second to actually draw your shadow. In your case, your chess piece. You could use

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

to get the bitmap and alter it before drawing it on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

On `OnDragListener()`

private final class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            getResources().getDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
            break;
          ....
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

This should work. Good luck!

Comment: I dont like doing that because ACTION_DRAG_STARTED is being called like 100 times for some reason. I was thinking of using a fakeView for the shadowBuilder. But I dont know how to pass a View by value because it's being passed by reference and so the actual view is also having its background changed...

Comment: you can restore your background when MOUSE_UP is called.

Comment: Ok then try @RobinDeCroon's answer